# How to setting up EventBridge to pass 2 different static json to AWS Lambda Function and 2 crons using cloudformation with yaml?

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I would like to know if it's possible to obtain yaml code after configure a EventBridge with cron and passing static json to Lambda Function in console?

I would like to learn how I could code in yaml to configure a EventBridge with cron and pass two static json to Lambda Function. I've configured in console yet but I need to do in yaml.

Thank you!!

Comment: https://www.sentiatechblog.com/defining-a-scheduled-lambda-in-cloudformation This can be easily converted to a different yaml format (json is valid yaml so `yq` will turn that into standard yaml).  Role, Function, Schedule, and Permission all have to be there for this to work

Comment: It's a good material but I need about pass input/parameters to lambda function.

Comment: It's part of the event rule target https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html#cfn-events-rule-target-input